# How to check if a form variable is equal to something in Perl?

Tags: perl, forms, get

I'm new to perl and I've mainly worked with php in the past,

usually to check if a get variable is equal to something and then do something else if it is, i'd simply do

```
if ($_GET['page'] == 'news') { 
echo 'yessss';
}
```

but I'm not really sure what to do with perl :$ could anyone help me out? :)

Thanks!

Comment: the operator for comparing strings in Perl is `eq` - try that in place of == (which is for numbers) :)

Comment: You need to be more specific regarding which Perl web framework you use. There's no Perl built-in accesss to GET variables, and the answer will depend on framework/module. *CGI.pm* and its derivatives were answered by SHiNKiROU below. *Embperl* would be `if ($fdat{page} eq 'news') {}`. *Catalyst* would be similar to CGI.pm (`$c->req->param('page')`)

Comment: echo? did you really mean to tag this with php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, the module of CGI exists,
http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#SYNOPSIS
and `->param` gets an input parameter.

```
use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header();
if ($q->param('page') eq 'news') {
  print "...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl you have different operators for checking string versus integer equality
"==" returns true if the left argument is numerically equal to the right argument.
"eq" returns true if the left argument is stringwise equal to the right argument.